# Run a cmap only when searching

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I have the following mapping:

```
cnoremap <silent> <CR> <CR>:echo 'Enter pressed'<CR>
```

This works as expected; the `:echo` command runs every time I press `<CR>` in the command line. This is done when entering the commandline with `:`, `/`, `?`, `<C-r>`= (in insert), etc.

Is there any way to get the `:echo` command to run *only* if I enter the commandline with `/`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a mapping from my `vimrc` where I check if the command type is either *forward search* `OR` *backward search*:

```
cnoremap <expr> <Tab> getcmdtype() == "/" \|\| getcmdtype() == "?" ? "<CR>/<C-r>/" : "<C-z>"
```

See `:help getcmdtype()`.

For more granularity, you could use `getcmdline()` like I did in the function below. The value of `getcmdline()` is checked against a bunch of patterns to decide what to return instead of `<CR>`:

```
function! Shortcut()
    let cmdline = getcmdline()
    if cmdline =~ '\C^ls'
        return "\<CR>:b"
    elseif cmdline =~ '/#$'
        return "\<CR>:"
    elseif cmdline =~ '\v\C^(dli|il)'
        return "\<CR>:" . cmdline[0] . "jump  " . split(cmdline, " ")[1] . "\<S-Left>\<Left>"
    elseif cmdline =~ '\v\C^(cli|lli)'
        return "\<CR>:silent " . repeat(cmdline[0], 2) . "\<Space>"
    elseif cmdline =~ '\C^old'
        return "\<CR>:edit #<"
    else
        return "\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction

cnoremap <expr> <CR> Shortcut()
```

See `:help getcmdline()`.