# Map a key in "search mode"

Tags: key-bindings, search, normal-mode

"Search mode" [is not a true mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13039/is-search-a-true-mode-in-vim), but is it possible to create mappings that only apply while typing a search after `/` or `?`?

I am wondering how one would go about mapping `<C-f>` to start a search and mapping `<C-f>` again to cancel it. Starting the search would be easy to implement (`nnoremap <C-f> /`) but I would have no idea how to toggle it off with `<C-f>` again.

My workflow is fine with vanilla `/` or `?`, but I am wondering if it is possible out of curiosity, and maybe also to make my search keybindings consistent with other programs.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "cancelling" a search? To you simply want to make `<C-f>` to `<Esc>` when you are in the `/` prompt (like this `cnoremap <expr> <C-f> getcmdtype() == '/' ? '<Esc>' : '<C-f>'`) or is there something more complex? Also just to give my two cents: You mappings sounds like a bad idea remapping built-in feature of vim usually ends up in annoyances broken workflows, it's often much more efficient to just learn the built-in commands and to _extend_ them with mappings not to _reimplement_ them.

Comment: Great, this does the trick. I wanted a way to differentiate when a search was being done and `getcmdtype` is perfect. If you would like to write that as an answer, I will gladly accept it. About remapping, I think it's a balance, as everything. In this case, I was more curious about a `getcmdtype`-like functionality than anything else (in fact `/` and `?` are more ergonomic than `<C-f>`). Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Instead of adding a duplicate answer I'll vote to close your question as a duplicate of [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3180) it doesn't mean you question isn't good but you were effectively asking for the same thing as this other question with a less precise vocabulary :)